# Is an anonymous class an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous

Using the following as an example, the ButtonExample class contains a JButton. The ActionListener for the JButton is an anonymous class.

Within the actionPerformed() procedure of the anonymous class there is a call to otherProcedure(); which is part of the ButtonExample class and separate from the JButton itself.

Why is this anonymous class allowed to make reference to a method is a completely separate object? Is this related to Inner/Outer Class behavior?
Is this the general rule when using anonymous classes? Are anonymous classes Inner classes or something else?

```
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;    
public class ButtonExample 
{

    public ButtonExample()
    {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Button Example");  
        final JTextField tf=new JTextField();  
        tf.setBounds(50,50, 150,20);  
        JButton b=new JButton("Click Here");  
        b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
                    tf.setText("Hello World");
                    otherProcedure();
                }  
            });  
        f.add(b);f.add(tf);  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);   

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ButtonExample be = new ButtonExample();
    }

    private void otherProcedure()
    {
        System.out.println("Other Procedure");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)?

Comment: Yes, anonymous classes are always inner classes that can reference fields and methods of the outer class.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answers. It is what I suspected but just wanted confirmation. Greatly appreciate it.